# How to split datetime period data into monthyear based on unique values in a column in R

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, lubridate, period

I have a series of receivers that were deployed for various periods. The dataset looks like this:

| Receiver | start_dt | end_dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-19 15:43:00 | 2022-06-19 12:43:00 |
| 2 | 2021-08-19 15:43:00 | 2022-05-10 18:43:00 |
| 3 | 2021-12-19 15:43:00 | 2022-06-19 12:43:00 |

I would like to extract each monthyear that each receiver was deployed within the start and end dates such that each receiver is linked to each of it's respective monthyear's it was active. Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

| Receiver | monthyear |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05 |
| 1 | 2021-06 |
| 1 | 2021-07 |
| 1 | 2021-08 |
| 1 | 2021-09 |
| 1 | 2021-10 |
| 1 | 2021-11 |
| 1 | 2021-12 |
| 1 | 2022-01 |
| 1 | 2022-01 |
| 1 | 2022-02 |
| 1 | 2022-03 |
| 1 | 2022-04 |
| 1 | 2022-05 |
| 1 | 2022-06 |
| 2 | 2021-08 |
| 2 | 2021-09 |
| 2 | 2021-10 |
| 2 | 2021-11 |
| 2 | 2021-12 |
| 2 | 2022-01 |
| 2 | 2022-02 |
| 2 | 2022-03 |
| 2 | 2022-04 |
| 2 | 2022-05 |
| 3 | 2021-12 |
| 3 | 2022-01 |
| 3 | 2022-02 |
| 3 | 2022-03 |
| 3 | 2022-04 |
| 3 | 2022-05 |
| 3 | 2022-06 |

I am not sure if lubridate is the best option here? In my head it seemed relatively simple but I can't seem to make it work with it or using other examples on stack.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: For preciseness, can you confirm how many rows you are expecting in the output?

Comment: 14 for R1, 10 for R2, 7 for R3 for a combined number of rows of 31 rows (for this example). Thats from counting the number of months between the start and end dates (including the start and end months too) In the actual dataset there are ~100 receivers over various start and end dates.

Answer (score 2):

`reframe` lets us do most of the work in one line.

Here, I convert (if not already) the two datetime columns to datetime (receiving data in year-month-day-hour-minute-second order, hence `ymd_hms`), convert those to date with `as_date`, and convert those to the first of the respective month. Then we can use `reframe` to make a sequence of monthly rows for each Receiver's range of months.

```
library(lubridate); library(dplyr)
df |>
  mutate(across(ends_with("dt"), ~floor_date(as_date(ymd_hms(.)), "month"))) |>
  reframe(monthyear = seq.Date(start_dt, end_dt, "month"), .by = Receiver)
```

Result (if you like, you could convert to `tsibble::yearmonth` or convert to a string YYYY-MM with `mutate(monthyear = format(monthyear, "%Y-%m"))`

```
   Receiver  monthyear
1         1 2021-05-01
2         1 2021-06-01
3         1 2021-07-01
4         1 2021-08-01
5         1 2021-09-01
6         1 2021-10-01
7         1 2021-11-01
8         1 2021-12-01
9         1 2022-01-01
10        1 2022-02-01
11        1 2022-03-01
12        1 2022-04-01
13        1 2022-05-01
14        1 2022-06-01
15        2 2021-08-01
16        2 2021-09-01
17        2 2021-10-01
18        2 2021-11-01
19        2 2021-12-01
20        2 2022-01-01
21        2 2022-02-01
22        2 2022-03-01
23        2 2022-04-01
24        2 2022-05-01
25        3 2021-12-01
26        3 2022-01-01
27        3 2022-02-01
28        3 2022-03-01
29        3 2022-04-01
30        3 2022-05-01
31        3 2022-06-01
```

Comment: I'm getting a lot of use out of `reframe()`, thank you

Answer (score 1):

We create and expand a sequence of months rowwise between `start_dt` and `end_dt`.
With `format(monthyear, "%Y-%m")` we get the month and year.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with("dt"), ~ymd_hms(.))) %>% # if you already have datetime format you don't need this line
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(monthyear = list(seq(ceiling_date(start_dt, "month"), 
                              floor_date(end_dt, "month"), 
                              by = "month"))) %>%
  unnest(monthyear) %>%
  mutate(monthyear = format(monthyear, "%Y-%m")) %>%
  select(Receiver, monthyear) %>% 
  print(n=50)
```

```
  Receiver monthyear
      <int> <chr>    
 1        1 2021-06  
 2        1 2021-07  
 3        1 2021-08  
 4        1 2021-09  
 5        1 2021-10  
 6        1 2021-11  
 7        1 2021-12  
 8        1 2022-01  
 9        1 2022-02  
10        1 2022-03  
11        1 2022-04  
12        1 2022-05  
13        1 2022-06  
14        2 2021-09  
15        2 2021-10  
16        2 2021-11  
17        2 2021-12  
18        2 2022-01  
19        2 2022-02  
20        2 2022-03  
21        2 2022-04  
22        2 2022-05  
23        3 2022-01  
24        3 2022-02  
25        3 2022-03  
26        3 2022-04  
27        3 2022-05  
28        3 2022-06
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked great (other than having to call dplyr for select, but that's on my end I believe)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach using list-columns and resulting a slightly more compact solution.

```
library(libridate)
library(tidyverse)

# Create test data
df <- tibble(
  receiver = 1:3,
  start_dt = floor_date(as_datetime(c("2021-05-19 15:43:00", "2021-08-19 15:43:00", "2021-12-19 15:43:00")), "month"), 
  end_dt = ceiling_date(as_datetime(c("2022-06-19 12:43:00", "2022-05-10 18:43:00", "2022-06-19 12:43:00")), "month")
)

# Solution
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(monthyear = list(seq(start_dt, end_dt, "1 month"))) %>% 
  select(receiver, monthyear) %>% 
  unnest(monthyear)
# A tibble: 34 × 2
   receiver monthyear          
      <int> <dttm>             
 1        1 2021-05-01 00:00:00
 2        1 2021-06-01 00:00:00
 3        1 2021-07-01 00:00:00
 4        1 2021-08-01 00:00:00
 5        1 2021-09-01 00:00:00
 6        1 2021-10-01 00:00:00
 7        1 2021-11-01 00:00:00
 8        1 2021-12-01 00:00:00
 9        1 2022-01-01 00:00:00
10        1 2022-02-01 00:00:00
# ℹ 24 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to make a base R one-liner, but can't get the receiver in one go. Figuring out how to always include the end month in base R is a challenge. and the below is using `lubridate::months(1)`, what a pain.

```
df <- data.frame(receiver = 1:3,
                 start_dt = as.POSIXct(c("2021-05-19 15:43:00", "2021-08-19 15:43:00", "2021-12-19 15:43:00")), 
                 end_dt   = as.POSIXct(c("2022-06-19 12:43:00", "2022-05-10 18:43:00", "2022-06-19 12:43:00")))

list_of_months <- mapply(seq, 
                         trunc(df$start_dt), 
                         trunc(df$end_dt, "month") + months(1), 
                         "1 month")

data.frame(receiver  = rep(df$receiver, sapply(list_of_months, length)),
           monthyear = format(do.call(c, list_of_months), format = "%Y-%m"))

#    receiver monthyear
# 1         1   2021-05
# 2         1   2021-06
# 3         1   2021-07
# 4         1   2021-08
# 5         1   2021-09
# ...
```